# Voucher printing from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with multiple voucher printing from Excel.

In sheet No.2 I have following data:

In column A, I have put approximately 2000 dates (dd-mm-yyyy).
In Column B, I have voucher nos (approximately 2000 voucher nos).
In column C, I have a different description in each cell.
In column D, I have an amount of vouchers.
In column F, I have the name of the person to whom I am paying. This could be a few cells.
In column H, I have mentioned the reason for the payment. This also could be few cells as nature of work can be common.

In Sheet No.1, I have the format of the voucher (A5 size).

I want a VBA or a method for printing to PDF/or printer attached, all the above voucher in the format in Sheet No.1

Sample data is as follows:

- In Cell A1 -> 04 Apr 2017
- In Cell B1 -> VCH0005
- In Cell C1 -> "Being amount paid to "
- In Cell D1 -> 500.00
- In Cell F1 -> "Mr. John Doe"
- In Cell H1 -> "for carrying goods from our office to some other office"

On the click of a button, the above data will be printed in a particular
format which is designed in Sheet1 A5 size or A4 size.

How can I do it?

Comment: You might start writing your code using the macro recorder. When you get stuck you will find help here. So far you don't appear stuck. You appear to be looking for someone to write code for you. You won't normally find that on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code copies and paste the data from worksheet two into worksheet one and saves worksheet one as a .pdf file.  It will ask you which application you would like to use to write the worksheet as a .pdf file.  You can define the Excel application's ActivePrinter property if needed before using the ExportAsFixedFormat method.

Here is the code:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim filePath As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:H" & lastRow).Copy
    .Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
End With

filePath = "C:" 'Edit file folder path the .pdf file will be saved to
'Application.ActivePrinter = "" 'Set active printer property if desired
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=filePath & "voucherPrint.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```